# How to route traffic from multiple ips (with single NIC) in a server linux

Tags: linux, networking, centos, routing

I have server(CENTOS) with one NIC and it has multiple ip addresses let's say my ips are 192.168.1.10, and 192.168.1.11.

I would like to route route traffic from both ip's.

I am struggling solve this problem, can someone give me suggestions to resolve it?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Route it to where?

Comment: And what will be your networks for this IP addresses?

Comment: I would like to route all outgoing traffic from either of these 2 ip's. Both ip's are in same subnet.

Comment: I bet you asked for ip forwarding in a different way.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward or edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add this line: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: There should be nothing special you need to do. The machine should route traffic that originates on any of its local IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too clear what you want to do, but you may need to look at [source-based routing](http://www.wlug.org.nz/SourceBasedRouting). This enables you to route your traffic to potentially several gateways based on the source IP address.

Another option may be related which is to use different source IPs from your application. This actually depends on your application and whether it supports `bind` function or not (look at `man 2 bind`). An example will be the use of `telnet` with `-b` option to choose the source IP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do routing on a stick, i.e. a route on single physical interface, usually that's done between two VLANs so if you're switch supports VLANs then follow this post courtesy of Lazy Geek:
http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/intervlan-routing-using-centos-with-1-interface/